# Exception in constructor, java

Tags: java

I have a problem with a simple Java code. I am trying to throw the exception in Constructor and to handle it also there. But it is not going to compile, because, there is need to handle this exception also in main function. I'm getting error - "Unhandled exception type MyException" ( in main function). 
Iif I put the try and catch blocks in main it works well, but despite this fact, MyException is handled in Construcor of FailingConstructor class.

I am wondering why do I need to handle this exception twice?

```
   class MyException extends Exception{
       MyException()
       {
         System.out.println("Throws MyException");
       } 
   }

   public class FailingConstructor{
      int a;
      int b;

FailingConstructor(int a, int b) throws MyException
{

    try{
        this.a=a;
    if(this.a==9)
        {
            throw new MyException();
        }
    this.b=b;
    }catch(MyException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Wyjatek z poziomu konstruktora");
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    FailingConstructor nowy = new FailingConstructor(9,6);
    System.out.println(nowy.a);
    System.out.println(nowy.b);



}
```

}

Code with this main function works well:

```
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          try{
                  FailingConstructor nowy = new FailingConstructor(9,6);
              System.out.println(nowy.a);
              System.out.println(nowy.b);
          }
          catch(MyException e)
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }


        }
```

Comment: remove the `throws MyException` from the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared that you will throw an exception but you have not try catch for this in main.

If you do not want the exception outrside of the constructor you can remove throws, otherwise you need try catch in main.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple: remove `throws MyException` from the constructor. When it's there, the compiler is quite traumatized because some sort of checked exception could be thrown. It isn't smart enough to realize that such a checked exception would always be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `throws MyException` from your Constructor `FailingConstructor` declaration

Answer (score 0):

You can remove throws MyException in the FailingConstructor or you can remove the try/catch clause and just simple have the throws MyException statement. Whenever an exception is explicitly thrown (or with checked exceptions), the method handling that section must either have a mechanism to catch it or should explicitly declare that it will throw that Exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare the exception twice. You do not need to say `throws MyException` in the constructor - the `try`/`catch` block you have will handle it no problem. If you also say `throws MyException`, the compiler thinks that your constructor throws another exception besides the one you caught.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare that method will throws exception you ensure that some who use this function will handle it.

You can not declare exception in method main because it can not be handle.